# Where can I find the Slytherin Common Room in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Where's the Slytherin Common Room? I'm trying to find it, but I'm struggling.

I know it is somewhere in the basements if I'm not mistaken, but where?

Where exactly is it? Does someone have easy directions to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to it, all you need to do is head to the Lower Grand Staircase Floo Flame and look directly forward. Walk down the short stairwell and head directly into the wall straight in front of you. The snake border on the ground below will rise up and form a doorway if you're a Slytherin student. Enter it to get to the Slytherin common room (where you can also net a Floo Flame spot).

The Slytherin common room is harder to find due to its dungeon-like structure. The entrance resembles a normal wall so you'll need to do a bit of investigating to find the exact location.

[image: Hogwarts Legacy Slytherin Common Room Entrance]

Like the Gryffindor common room, you'll need a password to enter if you're a Slytherin student. Once you use the correct password, the resting snake statue will slither upward, arching its body to reveal the passageway to the common room.

[image: Hogwarts Legacy Slytherin Common Room Entrance]